# Django meta field ordering VS Django Rest Framework OrderingFilter

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am building an API with Django Rest Framework. For some models I use the
meta class field like that

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-time']
```

and it seems to be working fine.

Just now I came across DRF's `OrderingFilter`. What's the benefits of using that class instead of Django's built-in ordering? I believe that class is just a wrapper around Django's ordering, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `ordering` in the Meta class, you are hardcoding the default ordering in code.

The [`OrderingFilter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter) ordering filter allows your users to specify the ordering in their API requests by varying a query parameter, for example:

```
http://example.com/api/users?ordering=-time
http://example.com/api/users?ordering=username
```